# Como fazer com que o cursor esteja no Text ao inicio do programa?

Tags: tkinter, cursor

Gostaria de saber como fazer piscar o cursor num objeto `tkinter.Text` quando eu faço andar a aplicação, porque normalmente nenhum widget é selecionado. Gostaria de ter o mesmo efeito dum terminal quando é ligado, onde se vê o cursor piscar.

Este é o código que estou utilizando, mas não funciona:

```
self.prompt = tkinter.Text(self.root, bg=self.bg, fg=self.fg, insertbackground=self.fg)

self.prompt.insert(tkinter.END, self.PROMPT_M)
self.prompt.bind('<Return>', self.add_prompt)

self.prompt.pack()
self.prompt.focus()
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize `Entry.focus()`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()
entry.focus()

root.mainloop()
```